# How can I prevent users from installing my android application(.apk) from outside of the Google play store? is that possible

Tags: android, flutter, google-play, google-play-console

My application was developed using flutter, and it was recently published
I want users to install it only via Google play to increase the download count and to promote the app rating due to google play algorithms.

How can I prevent users from installing my android application(.apk) from outside of the Google play store like Shareit, wifi direct... or any other method.

is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Once your APK is online, it doesn't matter where, it should not be possible to avoid downloading it from third party websites like APK hero or, as you mentioned, sending it directly via Wi-Fi direct e.g.